# Apache not working on MAMP 3.5 after macOS Sierra upgrade

Tags: mamp, macos-sierra

This is the error it's loggin:

```
[Sun Sep 25 15:04:12 2016] [alert] (EAI 8)nodename nor servname provided, or not known: mod_unique_id: unable to find IPv4 address of "Jonathans-MacBook-Pro.local"
Configuration Failed
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to add this to your /etc/hosts file:

127.0.0.1    Jonathans-MacBook-Pro.local

Comment: After upgrade, I noticed my host entries were gone and that my self signed certificates were no longer trusted. I toggled the checkbox that enables/disables a host and re-trusted the certificates, and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just stop macOS Apache

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Comment: Getting the error: "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service"

Comment: This looks like it just stops apache? How is this solving anything?